# currency converter- why does my for loop in switch wont work? when i run my code only the first for loop works

Tags: java

`I have to do a code which user will input dollar amount and currency(which where the dollar will be converted) for example 15 YEN which 15 is the dollar amount and YEN is where to be converted.My code only runs in the first for loop which it will scan a string and split it but on second for loop which the conversion happens wont work.

```
       for(i=0;i<=3;i++){
       temp = sc.nextLine();
       Temp = temp.split(" ");
    }

       for(i=0,j=1;i<=3;i+=2,j+=2){
           switch (Temp[j]) {
               case "PHP":
                   conversion = Double.parseDouble(Temp[i])*51.23;
                   System.out.println("$"+Temp[0]+" CONVERTS TO "+df.format(conversion)+" PHP.");
                   break;
               case "POUNDS":
                   conversion = Double.parseDouble(Temp[i])*0.84;
                   System.out.println("$"+Temp[2]+" CONVERTS TO "+df.format(conversion)+" POUNDS.");
                   break;
               case "LIRA":
                   conversion = Double.parseDouble(Temp[i])*2040;
                   System.out.println("$"+Temp[4]+" CONVERTS TO "+df.format(conversion)+" LIRA.");
                   break;
               case "FRANCS":
                   conversion = Double.parseDouble(Temp[i])*9.85;
                   System.out.println("$"+Temp[6]+" CONVERTS TO "+df.format(conversion)+" FRANCS.");
                   break;
               case "MARKS":
                   conversion = Double.parseDouble(Temp[i])*3.23;
                   System.out.println("$"+Temp[8]+" CONVERTS TO "+df.format(conversion)+" MARKS.");
                   break;
               case "YEN":
                   conversion = Double.parseDouble(Temp[i])*260;
                   System.out.println("$"+Temp[10]+" CONVERTS TO "+df.format(conversion)+" YEN.");
                   break;
               default:
                   ;
                   break;
           }
        System.out.println("Invalid input, Please try again");
       }
```

Comment: I don't understand why you need a loop to type a single currency value

Comment: its not a single input.i need atleast 4 input from user. sorry if my question wasnt cleared.

Comment: Well, you might need at least 4 input values, but you only use the last one.

Comment: what are you trying to achieve by the first loop? can you give an example about the input?

Comment: Sample Input:
17 POUNDS
25 MARKS
228 YEN
1 PHP

Comment: and the output will be: Sample Output: 
$17 CONVERTS TO 14.28 POUNDS
$25 CONVERTS TO 80.75 MARKS
$228 CONVERTS TO 59280 YEN
$1 CONVERTS TO 51.23 PHP

Comment: Why can't you just run it multiple times? Also, a less cryptic naming scheme would help. "Temp" tells us nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can omit the second loop and include the switch statement inside the first loop:

```
  for(i=0;i<=3;i++)
  {
   temp = sc.nextLine();
   Temp = temp.split(" ");

       switch (Temp[1]) {
           case "PHP":
               conversion = Double.parseDouble(Temp[0])*51.23;
               System.out.println("$"+Temp[0]+" CONVERTS TO "+df.format(conversion)+" PHP.");
               break;
           // Other cases
           // ...
           // ...
           default:
               i--;
               System.out.println("Invalid input, Please try again");
       }
  }
```

and if you want to read all the `4` inputs (1 input per line) first before conversion then you need to store them in `ArrayList` of `String`s then pass them to the loop.

```
        ArrayList<String> lines = new ArrayList<>();

        for(int i=0;i<=3;i++)
            lines.add(sc.nextLine());

        for(int i=0;i<=3;i++)
        {
            String Temp[] = lines.get(i).split(" ");

            switch (Temp[1]) {
                case "PHP":
                    conversion = Double.parseDouble(Temp[0])*51.23;
                    System.out.println(Temp[1]);
                    System.out.println("$"+Temp[0]+" CONVERTS TO "+df.format(conversion)+" PHP.");
                    break;
                // Other cases
                // ...
                // ...
                default:
                    continue;
                    //i--;
                    //System.out.println("Invalid input, Please try again");
            }
```

Comment: This assumes the input is repeated. Comments seems to suggest it's one line

Comment: Thankyou @XBlueCode ! that was useful and clearer. all i need to do is some adjustments and im done. Thanks alot!

Comment: its okay it makes me understand my code clearer. bluecode was a huge help. and thanks to others for looking at my question. im new in java and a student. thankyou guys.

Comment: cricket, I explained the second case where all the input is stored in a list then it will be processed using a second loop which include the `switch` statement.

Comment: @XBluecode, looks like i need to make it 4 inputs first and print all the conversion at once. i tried various way to store it and all i get is syntax errors. i can input 4 of them at onces but only print the conversion of the last input. Do i need to do the arraylist? i having a hard time understanding it and using it in my code also arraylist is on classes category which is still far ahead for me cause i just started.

Comment: @AAAAAAAAAAAAAAA. Please check the second variant with `ArrayList` and you can customize the default case depending on your desired scenario but avoid `i--` or the loop will become infinite in this case.

Comment: i understand the code, its the same method with what i did but just not an arraylist i think i just havent grasp the java syntax.. it works cleanly but i just want to lastly ask if i can make a counter variable for "3" in the loops. I tried replacing it with a variable so that i can manipulate how many inputs i want not just 4 inputs but all i had is java error Index 1 out of bounds for length 1.my last question is optional cause you help me alot its just an addition question cause i did try to do it but it gives always an error. Thanks alot @XBlueCode ill work harder!

Answer (score 1):

You don't need two loops if your input is one line, then you only need one scan

The second loop likely doesn't work because you repeat i<=3, meanwhile it seems your input is longer than 4 items .It'd be better to use the length of the split string, and you only need one variable to index it

```
    String temp = sc.nextLine().split(" ");
    double conversion;
    for (int i = 0; i < temp.length - 1; i +=2) {
        String amount = Double.parseDouble(temp[i]);
        String currency = temp[i+1];
        System.out.print("$"+amount+" CONVERTS TO ");

        switch (currency) {
            case "POUNDS":
               conversion = amount * (14.28/17);  // based on your comment, this isn't 51.23
               break;
        } 

        System.out.print(conversion + " " + currency);
        System.out.println();
    }
```

For an optimizaion, it'd be better if you used a `Hashmap<String, Double>` for the conversion rates, rather than a switch

Comment: oh i see so thats the reason, thankyou so much for the explanation mister @cricket_007.

Comment: also about the 51.23 i didnt noticed i repeated it in all my conversion lines. i did alot of adjustments that i forgot to recorrect my conversion formulas.

Answer (score 0):

Your for loop can only execute once because every switch case statement has a **break** statement at the end. As others have mentioned, you should try doing this without a for loop.